# Unable to import from the current directory

Tags: java

I have two teeny-weeny java files - one, containing a tiny interface:

```
// SQL_Abstract.java
interface SQL_Abstract{
    public void connect();
}
```

and the second one, containing a microscopic class:

```
// MySQL.java

import SQL_Abstract;

class MySQL implements SQL_Abstract{
    public void connect(){
        // now does nothing
    }
}
```

Both these files - SQL_Abstract.java and MySQL.java - are in the same directory. I compiled the first file, like `$ javac SQL_Abstract.java` and got no errors and tried to compile the second file with `$ java -cp "." MySQL.java`, but now got some errors. Here (all!) error messages:

```
$ javac -cp "." MySQL.java
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
MySQL.java:1: error: '.' expected
import SQL_Abstract;
               ^
MySQL.java:1: error: ';' expected
import SQL_Abstract;
                    ^
MySQL.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
class MySQL implements SQL_Abstract{
      ^
    MySQL.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public void connect(){
           ^
MySQL.java:6: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
5 errors
```

I should add, that I'm extremely new to `Java` and guess that I'm doing a lot of wrong things. Hope, someone can show how to solve all this.

Comment: I switched to `$ java -cp "." MySQL.java` and got one error message - "Could not find or load main class MySQL.java"

Comment: Both of the classes are in the default package (i.e. you didn't name a package) - so you don't need to import at all. Also: use `java` to run - not with a file name, just class name - and `javac` to compile.

Comment: you can't import a class from the default package

Comment: @ RealSkeptic. Oh, you are right as always.

Comment: Thanks you, guys! Seems like RealSkeptic has already answered my question. I removed import statement and it works